# Format Amount field with comma and decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I format amount field with comma and decimal?
I am able to get commas but this function does not allow decimal in the field.

```
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate "[How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/149055/1456376)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')  
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fXrv2/

Comment: @Oskar Hane im following the same answer. But in-appropriate decimal points coming up when i'm using. For example if i want to type 123, it displays as 1.23

Comment: @Himanshu Yadav im following the same answer. But in-appropriate decimal points coming up when i'm using. For example if i want to type 123, it displays as 1.23